# Keyword didn't execute

Tags: python, robotframework

So here's my code and I was wondering why it would show that the test case ran successfully as per the *log.html* but the keyword **Send Success Message** did not execute whatsoever. It is provided that I imported the libraries for SMTP details but putting it here would be bad I guess. I have been working on this for the last 2 days and I can't really seem to find an answer.

```
*** Keywords ***
Send Success Message
    Log Hello There
    ${settings} Read YAML tests/email_settings.yaml
    ${sender} Set Variable ${settings[0]['sender']}
    ${recipient} Set Variable ${settings[0]['recipient']}

    Send Message sender=${sender}
    ...          recipients=${recipient}
    ...          subject=sample message
    ...          body=success email

*** Test Cases ***
Dry Test Run 
    ${settings} Read YAML tests/email_settings.yaml
    ${flag} Set Variable ${settings[0]['email_flag']}
    Run Keyword If ${flag} == "True" Send Success Message
```

Comment: Pat, is actual ${flag} value is True or "True"?  I.e. Your code checks equality for string value "True", not boolean True.